# How to extract or unnest an unnamed value from a nested or list column?

Tags: r, list, tidyverse, tidyr, purrr

The following df has a list column (`CVcCVq`) that has a single numeric value. I would like to extract this single value into another column or convert this list column into a numeric column.

I have used the below code to extract elements of a list in the past (e.g., by using `.x$value`), but I cannot figure out how to reference the unnamed(?) value in (`CVcCVq`):

```
df <-
   df %>% 
   mutate(CVcCVq = map_dbl(CVcCVq, ~ .x$value))
```

Here is a sample of the dataframe I'm working with:

```
df <- 
   structure(list(site = c("Hungerford", "Hungerford", "Hungerford", 
"Hungerford", "Hungerford", "Hungerford"), date = structure(c(16244, 
16244, 16244, 16244, 16245, 16245), class = "Date"), q = c(0.13302763934, 
0.13302763934, 0.13302763934, 0.13302763934, 0.118154355, 0.118154355
), year = c(2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014), var = c("DOC", 
"NO3", "SRP", "turb", "DOC", "NO3"), value = c(8.41162692329658, 
2.68458225207895, 0.0100915159605364, 8.0213, 8.23726061695833, 
2.49696316297646), CVcCVq = list(0.129399469450364, 0.504972938773432, 
    1.13463616961327, 0.602451097752468, 0.129399469450364, 0.504972938773432)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), groups = structure(list(site = c("Hungerford", "Hungerford", 
"Hungerford", "Hungerford"), year = c(2014, 2014, 2014, 2014), 
    var = c("DOC", "NO3", "SRP", "turb"), .rows = structure(list(
        c(1L, 5L), c(2L, 6L), 3L, 4L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `unlist()`, `unnest()`, or extract with subsetting `[[` here.
I recommend you stick with `unnest()` here. It is more consistent and clear, and easier to use if you have multiple nested list columns.

```
library(dplyr)

df%>%mutate(CVcCVq=unlist(CVcCVq))

#OR

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df%>%unnest(cols=CVcCVq)

#OR

df%>%mutate(CVcCVq=`[[`(CVcCVq, 1))

#OR

df%>%mutate(CVcCVq=CVcCVq[[1]])
```

```
# A tibble: 6 x 7
# Groups:   site, year, var [4]
  site       date           q  year var    value CVcCVq
  <chr>      <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Hungerford 2014-06-23 0.133  2014 DOC   8.41    0.129
2 Hungerford 2014-06-23 0.133  2014 NO3   2.68    0.505
3 Hungerford 2014-06-23 0.133  2014 SRP   0.0101  1.13 
4 Hungerford 2014-06-23 0.133  2014 turb  8.02    0.602
5 Hungerford 2014-06-24 0.118  2014 DOC   8.24    0.129
6 Hungerford 2014-06-24 0.118  2014 NO3   2.50    0.505
```

You can also use a variant of your own code:

```
df%>%mutate(CVcCVq=map_dbl(CVcCVq, ~.x))
```

Comment: `df%>%mutate(CVcCVq=unlist(CVcCVq))` worked for the df subset I shared, but not for the full df. I got the following error when trying it with the full df: `Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `CVcCVq`.
ℹ `CVcCVq = unlist(CVcCVq)`.
ℹ `CVcCVq` must be size 146 or 1, not 117.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: site = "Hungerford", year = 2014, var = "DOC".`

Comment: Both `df%>%unnest(cols=CVcCVq)` and `df%>%mutate(CVcCVq=`[[`(CVcCVq, 1))` worked on the subset and full dataframe! Thank you!

Comment: `df%>%mutate(CVcCVq=CVcCVq[[]])` did not work on either the subset or the full df. It just dropped the `CVcCVq` column altogether

Comment: `df%>%mutate(CVcCVq=map_dbl(CVcCVq, ~.x))` worked with the subset I shared, but not the full df. I got the following error: Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `CVcCVq`.
ℹ `CVcCVq = map_dbl(CVcCVq, ~.x)`.
x Result 118 must be a single double, not NULL of length 0
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: site = "Hungerford", year = 2014, var = "DOC".

Comment: I recommend you stick with unnest here. It is more consistent and clear, and easier to use if you have multiple nested list columns. the others, as shown, can fail if you have NULL list elements as i suspect you may have